# There is no Software Center, and I cannot install it

Tags: system-installation, release-loki

I installed loki on both, VMware Player and VirtualBox; it did not install software center on either. I tried to install it (1) from the appcenter - and like described in a previous note, it just hung showing 'starting'. (2) I tried a manual install with apt-get install software-center - it showed serveral failures with the basic message: No module named 'softwarecenter.distro."elementary"'. 
It did create the software center icon... but it can't be executed. Removing software center with apt-get purge software-center also results in several
error messages, with a final pop-up to report the problem. As the documentation describes software center as a basic 'feature' of elementary this really should work straight out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I found on:

> > https://itsfoss.com/fix-application-installation-issues-elementary-os-loki/
> >
> > "Now, there are two ways to install the .deb packages: command line way and GUI way.
> >
> > If you go by command line, there are numerous ways to install the .deb packages but I’ll go with the simplest one. Open a terminal and use the following command:
> >
> > sudo apt install
> >
> > Alternatively, you can use a dedicated GUI application gDebi. gDebi is a lightweight and yet powerful application for installing .deb packages. It is particularly useful in handling dependencies. This is why I have often advised to make gDebi the default application to install programs.
> >
> > You can install gDebi from the AppCenter. Just search for it. You can also install it via the command line. Just use the command below:
> >
> > sudo apt install gdebi
> >
> > Once you have installed gDebi, right click on the .deb package and choose to open with gDebi. That’s it."

There is also the soluntion found by this user.

> > https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7191/5824

By doing this you should be able to install ubuntu software-center as they have explained.

Hope this helps.